# Is there a way in native API to get results of chrome task manager?

Tags: google-chrome, winapi, google-chrome-extension

Determination of PID of extension from Chrome task manager is trivial:
[image]

We just go to `Task Manager` and look for Process Id of a specific extension. Here, in the image PID of metamask extension is 1704.

Now, if we examine Chrome processes in Process Explorer (Windows), we see the following:
[image]

The same process with PID 1704 without nice metamask name.

**So my question is**: is there a way using native Win32 API to determine what extension runs in a specific Chrome process?

Note: examining chrome execution path gives that this specific instance runs an extension but no mention which one:

[image]

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, you couldn't use native Win32 API to determine what extension runs in a specific Chrome process. More details about the extension could only be obtained from Chrome's built-in task manager.

Comment: This is implemented in Edge browser that intentionally exposes this info to the Windows Task manager. Look for their blog post about that for more insights and info about internals.

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT Is there a way to programatically interact with Chrome Task Manager? Some IPC mechanism maybe?

Comment: In my opinion, there is no suitable winapi to interact with Chrome Task Manager. Maybe you could use some third-party libraries to achieve. (eg:Puppeteer)